# Securing a React frontend and with Python API using AWS Cognito

Tags: reactjs, authentication, pyramid, amazon-cognito

I'm considering using AWS Cognito as a user management system for a single page web app I'm building using React along with a Python REST API backend (Pyramid). I'm struggling to see how all the pieces fit together for my architecture (the docs don't seem to be helping me). There are many great examples of how to implement authentication into the frontend using JS. My issue is how to integrate this authentication into my backend REST API.

In my current hand rolled user management system, the frontend calls the REST API on sign-in and is given a token which is passed to API again for every subsequent request. I'm then able to use ACL's on my API functions, check permissions to access resources, etc. If I were to use Cognito and perform the authentication on the frontend (as many examples do) how will my backend know if the token is valid when it receives it with a request? Surely I wont have to call Coginto from the backend to verify this for every request? Also how can I perform checks for information such as 'is this user in the admin group' if that group is defined within Cognito? Again, calling out to Cognito for every request seems very heavyweight and cumbersome.

I did see one example where a list of valid tokens was exported from Cognito as a JSON file and kept on the backend. This seems horribly static when users could be added and removed regularly.

Is Cognito really suitable for my use case? Some high level guidance and pointers to any relevant examples and docs would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating with Cognito, the user can have 3 tokens:

- Refresh
- Access
- ID

For python, boto3 can interface now with Cognito. There's also this python lib wrapper: [warrant](https://github.com/capless/warrant#authenticate), to make it easier.

Once you have the token, it is possible to pass it to the API (eg: access) and it can be checked on the server side with [python-jose](https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), as per AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)

To pass the token, an example pyramid /login implementation can keep the information in the session before setting the request response:

```
request.session['my_token'] = str(a_token)
```

The [default cookie session factory](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/sessions.html) works, though it warns that the token is not sent encrypted.